# Levi-Civita with binary multi-index

Tags: matrices, tensors, binary, skew-symmetric-matrices

Consider the Levi-Civita symbol $\varepsilon_{ijkl}$ where $i,j,k,l \in \{0,1,2,3\}$. Consider now the binary representation of $i,j,k$ and $l$, such that $i \to (i_0 \, i_1)$, $j \to (j_0 \, j_1)$, $k \to (k_0 \, k_1)$ and $l \to (l_0 \, l_1)$. Is there a closed form of the Levi-Civita symbol in the form of

$$ \varepsilon_{ijkl} \equiv \varepsilon_{(i_0 \, i_1) (j_0 \, j_1) (k_0 \, k_1) (l_0 \, l_1)} = \textrm{function of 2-dimensional Levi-Civita tensors   ?} $$

I have been trying to find an answer by direct inspection without any success. Thanks!

Comment: You could use $i_0=\varepsilon_{0i_0}$ etc. to write the whole thing as a function of eight $2$-dimensional Levi-Civita tensors, but you might not like that choice of function. Can you make the rules more precise? For example, does the result have to be a polynomial in the $\binom{8}{2}$ tensors we can make out of $2$ of the $8$ indices? (Since $\varepsilon_{ab}^3=\varepsilon_{ab}$, we can assume without loss of generality that such a polynomial's terms are each of degree $\le2$ in each such tensor.)

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Good point, I would be interested in combinations like $\varepsilon_{i_0 j_1}\varepsilon_{i_0 j_2}\cdots$ and so on, such that the indexes are summed over, without any of them fixed.